# Allowing users to create subusers in Drupal7, and allowing them to add paid services to both accounts

Tags: module, drupal-7, user-management

First post here! Although StackOverflow has been invaluable for years...

So I'm working on a Drupal 7 site for a local non-profit. The goal of the site is, among other things, to allow people to sign up for membership to the organization. These memberships are paid, and vary depending on what the particular service is (some will be one-time charges, some recurring). I think I can handle the payment parts with ubercart or something similar, but the problem is figuring out how to allow the main members to add subusers to their accounts. The main members are allowed to add their family members to their account for no extra charge, so a user may have several subusers (such as children and spouse).

I have tried the Subusers module, but it seems to be buggy, doesn't work as expected, and isn't being maintained or fully ported over to D7. I have researched Organic Groups and that seems to be more suited to large groups of people. There is Relation, but I'm just not sure how to implement it along with other modules to get this to work.

Does anybody have any suggestions or hints to point me in the right direction? I really want to learn how to do this, because I plan to use Drupal for some other projects after this is complete. Thanks!

Comment: There's a StackExchange dedicated to Drupal: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/. I'm sure they'll be able to get you pointed in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't know a Drupal exchange existed...